# How can i adjust CPU frq. in Lubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, lubuntu, cpufreq

In Gnome 2 there was panel applet that one could use to do that, however in Lubuntu there isn't one, how can i adjust it then?.

Preferably with a simple method, don't really want to directly edit any system file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CPUFreq script

The is a [lightweight script](http://linux-apps.com/content/show.php/CPU+frequency+governor+selector?content=124444) available.

Download and save with the filename "cpufreq.sh".

Now install *zenity*

```
sudo apt-get install zenity
```

Give the script execute permissions

```
cd ~/Downloads
chmod +x cpufreq.sh
```

When you want to change cpu-frequency run

```
~/Downloads/cpufreq.sh
```

[image]

---

### Lubuntu Plugin

*This is how Lubuntu/LXDE should work... however its been broken since 11.04.  Hopefully in the near future this problem is resolved and this comment can be deleted*

Right-click the panel and choose...

[image]

Click the Add button...

[image]

Add CPUFreq - this will add an icon to your desktop to change CPU frequency

[image]

<sub>Note - I dont have a PC that has scalable CPU frequencies to test this applet... let me know if it works for you</sub>

Comment: Oh, how i missed this, one thing though i can't click on the applet? to adjust anything, only a window pop ups with "remember governor.." but i can't actually change the governor, anyways, seems like this applet is not as capable as the one in gnome 2.Thanks

Comment: curious - if it is not a click - is it instead a right-click to change the frequency?  Otherwise it sounds like a bug that needs to be reported.

Comment: Nope, right-clik brings the contextual menu, left click doesn't do anything, i searched in the LXDE forums came across 2 threads with this same issue, none of them had an answer they were dated 2009 so i don't think the LXDE guys are fixing this, i had to use a script to change the governor.

Comment: I found this script that looks lightweight - you just need to install the package `zenity` to use it - https://www.linux-apps.com/content/show.php/CPU+frequency+governor+selector?content=124444

Comment: That's the script i'm using :D.